# When working with web.config, Configuration class is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces, web-config

I want to access the "appSettings" section of a web.config file. According to MSDN and multiple other sources, the following should work:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = 
    WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/rootPath");
```

I received this error on the second configuration (System.Configuration.**Configuration**):

> The type or namespace name
>   'Configuration' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Configuration'(are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)

I received an additional error on system (**System**.Configuration.Configuration):

> The type
>   'System.Configuration.Configuration'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced.  You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.Configuration,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Addressing the first error, I have a reference to System.Configuration.  When I look in Object Browser, it contains a class definition for Configuration.

Addressing the second error, the reference is for version 2.0.50727.  Is there a version 2.0.0.0?

The second error popped up after I deleted, and re-added the reference to System.Configuration.  Also, after re-adding the reference it now displays as "System.**c**onfiguration" in my references.  Note the lowercase c.

**Additional Notes**
Things I've tried and failed:

- Deleted and added the reference to
  System.Configuration
- Deleted all references for the project and added them back
- Checked out a clean solution from SVN

I created a test solution and had no problems accessing the class in the System.Configuration namespace.

Any ideas on what is going on (how did I eff this up)? What avenues can I try to fix it?

Comment: Regarding 2.0.0.0 and 2.0.50727 they are exactly the same thing. Each assembly in .NET typically has two versions in it: an assembly version and a file version. The assembly version is 2.0.0.0 and the file version is 2.0.50727.

Comment: Regarding the problem itself: Where is the code that you are trying to write? It is in an ASPX file? In a CS file? If so, what folder is the file in? There are two sets of references in a Web Application Project depending on what kind of file you are working on and where it is located.

Comment: Eilon - this was the cause of my issue. Thanks for taking the time to post your answer.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, for some reason `System.Configuration` was missing from my MVC 3 application with the same error. Adding this reference appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so stupid, I want to delete this question and quietly back away.  Perhaps it'll be useful to some other fool.  Eilon was on the right track, I was adding the reference to the **wrong project**.

I was in a time crunch trying to get a project production ready and was not very focused (trying to do several things at once).  Ah well, I'm still new to this and hopefully next time I will take a deep breath and not stress out...and start the project out with connection strings stored in the web config.

Comment: Well, I'll raise my hand and admit I was one of those "other fools."  :-)  Thanks for not deleting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove that references to `System.Configuration` and do it from scratch: you should to add `version=2.0.0.0` (for **runtime** version v2.0.50727). Then, to read your `appSetting`, you could just write this:

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourKey"];
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious why it's looking for that version.  My Framework folder doesn't contain a version 2.0, just 1.0.3705, 1.1, 2.0.50727, 3.0, and 3.5.  So I'll have download from MSDN.  This seems like an atypical step, like something must be messed up with my references.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried.  When I added it back, it displayed with the the lowercase c: "System.configuration", and displayed the second error mentioned.

Comment: That lowercase `c` is "right": I got this here too; but I didnt understood your second error, can you please clarify it?

Comment: The second error was "The type 'System.Configuration.Configuration' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced...".  

As a sanity check I created a quick project and had no problem accessing the classes in the System.Configuration namespace (including Configuration and ConfigurationManager).  So it's definitely a wonky issue with that project's references, I'm just unclear on how fix it.  I'll try removing all of my references and adding them back one by one.